# How to make a message appear once email is submitted using React and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, nodemailer

I am using React and have built an email form. I currently have this class: `<div className="msg">Message has been sent</div>` but only want it to appear when the message has successfully sent. So only when the following resolves as status: true. How can I target this using only React/CSS?

````
  .post('/api/email', values)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("Server responded")
    setValues({
      name: "",
      email: "",
      message: "",
      status: true
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      window.alert("Email not sent")
    });```
````

Answer (score 0):

if your status varible named status then

```
<div className="msg" style={{display: status ? "block" : "none"}}>Message has been sent</div>
```

That's it.

And I suggest that you should add following code.

````
.catch(err => {
setValues({
  name: "",
  email: "",
  message: "",
  status: false
  })
  console.log(err);
  window.alert("Email not sent")
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the div between curly brackets, and add a `condition &&` should do the work:

```
{values.status && <div className="msg">Message has been sent</div>}
```